# Run script from another home

Tags: linux, bash, shell, chmod

I have a script in a user `/home` directory and I want to execute this script with an other user.
The script is in UserA home :
`/home/UserA/command/command.sh`

I want to execute this script with `/home/UserB`

What I did and wanted to know if there is an easier way to do it , is :

1. I gave the right to write and execute on this directory to other (`chmod 703`): `/home/UserA/command`
   Is there a way to give the right only to UserB instead of other ?
2. In `/home/UserB/.bash_profile` , I added in the path `/home/UserA/command`

Another problem, I have, is that in the script `command.sh`, I use a variable `$LISTPATH` (`$HOME/List`) and this variable is defined in the UserA  `.bash_profile`.

So when I start the script from `/home/UserB`, this variable is always empty.
Do I need to also add this variable in the `.bash_profile` of UserB:
`$LISTPATH=/home/UserA/List`

Thanks for your help

Comment: The other user shouldn't need to write to `/home/userA/command`. It just needs execute.

Comment: Why don't you put `LISTPATH=$HOME/List` in the script itself instead of the profile?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that you want it to point back to userA. Then you could just put `LISTPATH=~userA/List` in the script.

Comment: But if some users could have different `List` paths, then you do need them to each put it in their `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Better would be to set a default value for `LISTPATH` in the script if it has not already been defined: something like `LISTPATH="${LISTPATH:-~userA/List}"`.

Comment: If I put LISTPATH=$HOME/List in the script, when I run the script from userB it will point to /home/userB/List and this directory does not exist under userB.  I gave the write because the script is writing a log under /home/userA/List

Comment: thanks guys. @Barmar, I removed the write permission. But I needed to add Read and Execute, otherwise from userB, I got the error message Permission denied

Comment: I think it's time to reorganize your stuff instead of looking for workarounds. Move scripts that should be shared to a common location (i.e. /usr/local/bin) and add default values for variables and overwrite them with local values as indicated in previous comments.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for a workaround for a different problem. What does the script do for UserA and UserB? Why would the two users have to interact via this script?

Comment: Another oddity that I see here is `I added in the path /home/UserA/command` I'm not sure what your trying to say here. You added '/home/UserA' to UserB's PATH in their `.profile`?

Answer (score 1):

What a mess!
In my opinion:

1. You can create a group which UserB belongs to so you can assign this group to /home/userA/command and set right permission (such as chmod 730 /home/userA/command).
2. You better put the variable $LISTPATH on the top of your script.

Anyway, I think you better reorganize your project, you better put the script in /opt/< some subfolder>... instead of /home/userA/command.